# How to compare the working tree with a commit?

Tags: git, diff

I'm using

```
git diff mycommit
```

for comparing my working tree with `mycommit`, but it seems to ignore files not present in the current index. You can reproduce it as follows:

```
git init
echo A > A.txt; git add .; git commit -m A; git branch A
echo B > B.txt; git add .; git commit -m B; git branch B
git reset --hard A
echo BB > B.txt
git diff B
```

The output (as of git version 1.7.3.3) is empty. Using `--diff-filter=ACDMRTUXB` shows "deleted file" which is wrong as well, since the file `B.txt` exists both in the working tree and in commit `B`. IMHO, the file should be shown as modified. Surprisingly, it works after adding the file to the index, although it's not the index what gets compared. How can I get the right diff without it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

manojlds wrote in his answer

> Basically, diff does not take into account untracked files. That is why you see that the file is deleted, because the diff is same as git diff B A

This is true and worth upvoting, but it didn't satisfy me, as it says neither "how can I compare it" nor gave the deeper reason behind it. I still thought it was a bug, so I asked at the git forum and got a [long answer](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/203689/focus=203702) by somebody who surely knows. The important parts for me are:

> The definition of paths in the working tree in these sentences is not "all files on the filesystem", or "all files on the filesystem, filtered with the ignore mechanism".  It is "all files on the filesystem that are in the index" ...

and

> ...that will give a clean semantics to "git diff HEAD": what change would I be recording if I said "git commit -a" at this point?

Answer (score 108):

A simple graphic might be of help:

[image]

So there are three types of diff you can ask for:

1. `git diff --cached`
   This is the difference between what is in the index and the last commit. It shows you that changes that will be in the next commit.
2. `git diff`
   This shows the difference in between the index and the working tree. These are the changes that you have made to files since you last added them to the index. This is why I wasn’t getting any results. I had no changes between the index and the working tree.
3. `git diff HEAD`
   This shows the difference between the files in the working tree and the last commit. There is a gotcha here: if you've made changes, added them to the index, and then backed out these changes in the working tree, you’ll get no results for `git diff HEAD` (because there is no difference) but you will get output for `git diff --cached` because there are still changes in the index.

And if you want to compare it against previous commits:

[image]

This just compares against the previous commits, but you can replace `HEAD~` with any other reference to a commit.

Comment: where is the answer to the question?

Comment: Very good answer, the graphic really help to explain it, certainly cleared a few things up for me.

Comment: Just one clarification. I don't know, maybe something's changed since the date of the answer (currently I use version 2.17.0). According to the answer, if I edit something in the _working_ _tree_, do **not** add it in the _index_ and use `git diff a_file.xyz`, I should get no result. Instead I get the same results as if I used `git diff HEAD a_file.xyz`. So, it looks like that, currently, if the _index_ is empty (or, at least, the file, for which you try to get the differences, is not in the _index_) git automatically shows the differences between the _working_ _tree_ and the _HEAD_.

Answer (score 10):

The question is: I have added some file in my working tree, that exists in the other commit. Why is `git diff <commit>` not showing me the difference between the file content that exists in my working tree and the content of the file that is in the other commit.

This is because the new file that you added is untracked and hence, well, git doesn't track it.

Try `git diff HEAD` you won't see that you have added B.txt in your working tree.

Basically, diff does not take into account untracked files. That is why you see that the file is deleted, because the diff is same as `git diff B A`

Now, if you were to add the file, you will see the expected result, because git is tracking it now.

**Say, you committed the file and then modify the content in the working tree:**

Now, `git diff HEAD` will show the difference between working tree and HEAD, showing the change you have done in your working tree on tracked files. Same with `git diff B`

Comment: Well your comment was "You don't seem to have understood the question that the OP is asking". If that's true then neither do you, because I said exactly the same thing as you.

Comment: @BenLee - you might have meant the same thing, but I don't think you are saying the same thing.

Comment: How was I saying anything different? That's exactly what I said. The file doesn't exist in the working tree (git status shows it's 'untracked') but if you add it it will show the diff. That's what I said. And that's what you said too.

Comment: `but if you add it it will show the diff.` - I didn't finish at that. I  came to the point of modifying tracked file in working tree which is what `git diff B` is meant to show. Also, see my comment on your answer.

Comment: I don't see how your addition adds anything that the OP doesn't already know. But you know, I give up. I understand how this works, and don't need to prove it to you, it's just not worth my time to argue any more.

Comment: Deleted my post since yours explains it better anyway. Upvoted yours.